# TYPO3 Realurl in Composer Mode

Tags: composer-php, typo3, realurl

I am using TYPO3  in composer mode and right now, I am stuck with an unsupported version of TYPO3 (Version 8.4) because my only dependency EXT:RealURL requires TYPO3 < 8.5, thus preventing me from upgrading.

```
{
    "repositories": [
            { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" }
    ],
    "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
    "description" : "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "require": {
            "typo3/cms": "^8.4",
            "typo3-ter/realurl": "^2.1"
    },
    "extra": {
            "typo3/cms": {
                    "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
                    "web-dir": "web"
            }
    }
```

}

RealURL composer.json

```
 "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": ">=6.2.0,<8.5.0",
        "php": ">=5.4.0"
    },
```

I am not sure what my options are right now:

Deal with an unsupported version auf TYPO3 or abandon RealURL, breaking existing URLs, or ?

It would be great if you could point out, if I am missing a viable option here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until realurl is updated you may use:

```
"require": {
    "typo3/cms": "8.5.1 as 8.4.99",
    "typo3-ter/realurl": "^2.1"
}
```